# share code between angular and nodejs projects

Tags: node.js, angular, libraries, package.json

I have some classes which were initially written for my Angular front-end, which I would also like to use in the NodeJS backend.

Those classes are written in typescript, while my NodeJS backend is written in javascript.

What would be the most **straightforward** way to share this code between both projects, so that both can use the same source code in the future?

It would be a bonus of course, if I could keep the code in typescript and private. But my fear is, that I will have to rewrite it to javascript and create a public npm package for them.

Comment: In short, it might be a challenge. TypeScript is transpiled to JavaScript. Using TypeScript syntax on your Node.JS codebase without any form of TS configuration/setup will result in your compiler screaming out errors at you..

Comment: @wentjun Given the fact that all angular projects have a free choice between js and ts (and other languages), does that mean that all angular dependencies have to be written in javascript ? (It's an honest question, I have no clue.) - Of course, I was hoping that perhaps there would be a trick to it. In best case, perhaps a template project that would do the magic for me. In other words, a clever configuration in the package.json that would magically transpile code when necessary.

Comment: me too. Honestly you have raised a very good question there. Hmm.. I believe most Angular dependencies are written in JS/TS, except of course, there might be some exceptions. Yeah, I think you might be going at the right direction, though I personally can't provide any advice to creating a template that is compatible across both frameworks!

Comment: In mean time I migrated the backend to typescript, and it took less than a day. - Still curious about this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Nx](https://nx.dev/angular/getting-started/what-is-nx). It allows you to create libraries which can be shared between a frontend app (e.g. Angular) and a backend Node.js app.

Answer (score -2):

> You can share some of the code between Angular and Node projects,for that you need to choose '**Nest'  framework** on the node side.
>
> Benifits of Nest

1. It uses typescript
2. It follows the same syntax as Angular
3. It follows modularity in the architecture

[For detailed information, please follow official nest website](https://nestjs.com/)

> xplat - cross platform

This cross platform already has the solution to your problem.

[xplat official website](https://nstudio.io/xplat)

Comment: In mean time I migrated my back-end to typescript without using nest.